# Can my daughter charge my credit card from her Apple ID?

Tags: mac-appstore, ios-appstore, apple-id

If I set up an individual account for my daughter can she charge my credit card with an app purchase?

Answer (score 8):

If your credit card is associated with her Apple ID, yes.

Comment: I suggest you to add this isn't the highest risk. If the account of Rudollph' daughter is hacked, then the credit card of Rudolph may be charged with what everyone guess. Beware in reality these robberies won't be huge, but on the contrary small and irregular to avoid any notice.

Comment: @danielAzuelos That risk applies to all Apple ID accounts with a credit card, not just to the situation here.

Comment: This risk is a general probability which is the same for everyone, this is math. right ☺. But… I think that I will be able to detect this robbery faster than my daughter (it might be necessary to confirm this ☺). Hence the risk exposure is different, and the total risk is consequently different.

Answer (score 0):

Is Apple ok with it? - yes
Would I do it? - probably not

---

If my daughter was young, I'd gift her an allowance and augment with larger gifted apps when needed or have some gift cards handy (you can often get them at 20% off at warehouse stores and online from time to time). If she were older, I'd want to get her a credit card account either on her own or tied to mine so she can start on managing her finances.

If neither of the above options makes sense for you, you most likely you will be able to specify your billing address on her Apple ID. Should you be comfortable giving her control over your credit card to make purchases, it's your decision which accounts you choose to store that billing information and who has access to the password and security questions.

I would say that if you want to use that credit card with other Apple accounts, you might find one or both locked so it might be easier to set up an allowance or get her her own credit card (in your name or hers) number so that she has a cleaner setup.

Apple does use the name on the billing contact for the default name on Game Center and some other places, so your daughter might be not only spending your money, but representing you in some of her online activities.

Comment: this is where the setup is beneficial where you do not tie the account to a CC, and you instead use iTunes cards to fund the balance. This is what I do at a school whose iPads I manage, and they simply accept donations via iTunes cards and they make their purchases that way.

Comment: I do the same thing for businesses when they run a pilot project and don't yet know what apps they need or want to jump through administrative hoops to sign up for Volume Purchase Program.